# Why does glob fail when I call my function twice in Php

Tags: php, glob

My glob() code written following:

```
$site1 = glob("../htdocs/site1-*.txt");
$random_site1 = $site1[array_rand($site1)];
$site1_shuffle = file("$random_site1");

$data[site1] = implode("\r", array_slice($site1_shuffle, 0, 100));
$data[site1] = str_replace("\n\r", "", $data[site1]);

$site2 = glob("../htdocs/site2-*.txt");
$random_site2 = $site2[array_rand($site2)];
$site2_shuffle = file("$random_site2");

$data[site2] = implode("\r", array_slice($site2_shuffle, 0, 1));
$data[site2] = str_replace("\n\r", "", $data[site2]);
$data[site2] = trim($data[site2]);
```

I need to create two function as $data[site1] and $data[site2].

When I write both into file then echo as  and  into template, and open web page url. It getting error as blank data or white page.

I trying to find which one is error by mark one of line $site1 = glob("../htdocs/site1-*.txt"); or $site2 = glob("../htdocs/site2-*.txt"); as a comment and reload web page url. It not getting any error and web page loading fine.

So, I doubt that what's the error when I using glob() two times in same page?

Is there any solution to solved the issue?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Paste your code not images with your code.